# Video Upload to imgur failed successfully via using curl

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, imgur

Image upload via `curl` works perfectly, but not for videos.
The [imgur api documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139) is outdated does not seem to work with video files.
The video file is fairy small, it's .mp4 file and the imgur api simply returns `null` errorcode.

Check the windows `curl` example below.
Before testing the code below, remember:

1. Insert your **Client-ID** into `YOUR_CLIENT_ID`
2. Adjust the file path of `-F "video=@`
3. Requirements `curl`:

   - Latest Windows 10 operating system that includes `curl.exe` binary.
   - Linux Distribution with `curl` binary.

**Windows Batch script example**.
save it with a file extension `yourfilename.bat` or `yourfilename.cmd`

```
@ECHO OFF
curl --request POST --url "https://api.imgur.com/3/image" --header "Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID" --header "content-type: multipart/form-data;" -F "name=testuploadname" -F "description=sdfdsf" -F "type=file" -F "video=@C:\Users\Windows10\Desktop\5757578.mp4" -F "disable_audio=1"
PAUSE
```

Output, video upload failed due to `null` errorcode:

```
{"data":{"errorCode":null,"ticket":"0c328b47"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

Comment: /image in the url is correct one as there are no other working ones and it is clearly mentioned in the imgur documentation that /image is the correct way to upload a video file.

Comment: /upload is old and and does not exist as a page in the imgur.com

Comment: video file size is irrelevant.

Comment: failed successfully: I mean that I think I did everything right and video still wasn't uploaded; instead I've got a response with an a unhandled internal error, errorcode : null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer YOURTOKEN" -F "video=@C:\Users\Windows10\Desktop\75427.mp4" https://api.imgur.com/3/upload
```